# New to DNN, can I run a site off my computer instead of a hosting site?

Tags: dotnetnuke

Is there anyway I can run a sit on my computer, like if I wanted to make a new website is there anyway I could just use my computer as the host. Also I've been sent me a DNN file, but it says the host site name isn't valid, can I make this file run off my computer or something so I don't need to buy a hosting website.

EDIT: I'm not wanting to host a web site from home, I just want to be able to edit the web site. I don't want to actually host the site from my computer I just want to use my computer to be able to edit the website without making any changes to the physical site. Like DNN7 comes with Awesome Cycles website, but it's not actually on the web, can I make a website and host it somewhere so I can make changes as I see fit, but not actually post the site to the web till I get ready.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run a *test* or play/development site on your computer, that's not connected to the Internet, sure -- look for LAMPP, WAMPP, or XAMPP packages. Note that they are often "bleeding edge", such as PHP 5.5 rather than 5.4. If you're thinking of making a real web site that's on the Web, be aware that hackers will have you for lunch. Don't put any serious site on your own computer, especially one handling money or sensitive information. Leave that to the pros, who are paid to worry about security all day.

Answer (score 0):

In general, yes you can host a website at home. However, the main reason why you wouldn't is that if your IP address changes, you need to update the DNS for your domain name. This adds several layers of complexity.

Also, network lag is likely to be high, and if you even moderate popularity, it will hose your home internet connection.

As to how you do all of that, I suggest you check out the documentation and tutorial for dotnetnuke, and go from there.

Answer (score 0):

You can run this from your computer at home by using the IP Address.  If your internet provider offers it, you can set it to keep the same IP address.

If your IP changes, you can google some "dynamic dns" services which will change your DNS pointer every time your IP changes.  Some are free and some charge, but you will still need to register the domain name if you don't want users to type the IP address.

I'm not sure what a DNN file is.  DNN is a website which usually contains many files and directories, and must be connected to a database.